# Create a transparent div over a td or tr element

Tags: html, css, transparency

I have a table and I would like to be able to set up a transparent div over the entire row to show that it is inaccessible at the moment.

Here is my a row from my table:

```
<tr id="post_1998">
  <td id="post_1998_image">
    ...content...
  </td>
  <td class="description">
    ...more content...
  </td>
  <td class="buttons">
    ...even more content...
  </td>
</tr>
```

Perhaps something like the following would be able to set the transparency but I don't know how you would construct the css.

```
<tr id="post_1998">
  <td id="post_1998_image">
    <div class="transparent">
    ...content...
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="description">
    <div class="transparent">
    ...more content...
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="buttons">
    <div class="transparent">
    ...even more content...
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by making the row inaccessible? Do you want to prevent users for selecting/clicking elements which are present in the row?

Comment: Yeah, in the context of the site, this transparency would be set using ajax to prevent the user from clicking any of the elements because there is an action on the server side.

Comment: With that logic, wouldn't it be easier to use JS to add/remove the triggers from the elements that cause the server-side actions?

Comment: Well, that is always an option. But I'd like to have something that gives the user a clear indication that some elements are being processed server side. Simply disabling the trigger elements wouldn't be explicit enough.

Comment: @vrish88: You cannot set transparency with AJAX. AJAX is NOT a framework. AJAX is NOT a library. AJAX does NOT interact with the DOM. It is a technology for communication between Javascript and a Web Server using XML as encapsulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the z-index value in CSS. Make the transparent divs using appropriate CCSS code which you will find easily with a Google search, and then set the z-index on that div to a higher value (say 20 - a random choice). This places the div over the other content.

You need two different settings for different browsers to achieve transparency (from memory).

Some possible help:

[Coding Day](http://www.codingday.com/transparent-div-span-for-all-browsers/) - making the div transparent

Answer (score 0):

You could add a "Transparent" CSS Class, then from this you can either use a transparent PNG or go with one of the other options for transparency.  [Here is an article](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/3431.htm) that talks a bit about transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty PNG image with transparency on that is 1 pixel by 1 pixel (it barely take any resources).

Here is an example in CSS for transparent div:

```
#transparent
{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    background-image: url('transparent_image.png');
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

You will have to give it some dimensions too (I did put any because I do not know what are the dimensions of you table nor where it is in the page).